# error comes as :- 'int' object is not subscriptable when i type latte

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, if-statement, while-loop

My replet link:- https://replit.com/@AdityaShukla29/Python-error-check?v=1

I tried the code in the replit, and when I type **latte** or **report**, it gives an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reusing the variable `coffee`.  It starts off referencing the entire menu:

```
coffee=Coffee.MENU
```

but later in your code you reassign it:

```
coffee=coffee[ask]["ingredients"]["coffee"]
```

After you've reassigned `coffee`, it points to an `int` (the amount of coffee in the `ingredients`).  The next time after that you try to look up an item in the menu dictionary that `coffee` previously pointed to, you get an error because it's not a dictionary any more, it's an `int`.

To fix this, use names that will help keep you from reusing variables accidentally.  I might suggest changing your `import` line to:

```
from Coffee import MENU
```

and then just using `MENU[ask][etc...]`.  Using the original name makes it easier for you to remember what it's referencing (the `MENU` global) and less likely to reassign it to something else.